# Select row prior as.freq() occurrence

Tags: python, datetime, pandas

My goal is to select a row(s) prior to an occurrence defined using time series analysis "as.freq" such as 'Q' (Quarter), 'EOM', etc...

For instance, in example below, df.asfreq('Q') yields following:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np 

dates = pd.date_range('20120101','20140101')
df =pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(len(dates),1),index=dates,columns=list('A')) 

df.asfreq('Q')

df
            A
2012-03-31  0.207220
2012-06-30  1.154098
2012-09-30  0.928301
2012-12-31  0.457587
2013-03-31  1.063016
2013-06-30  -0.650549
2013-09-30  0.562216
2013-12-31  -1.978959
```

Want to select row "prior" to first end of quarter(and subsequent 'Q') occurrence(s)(2012-03-31) above:

```
2012-03-30  0.314567
```

Or, rows say 2012-03-30 to 2012-03-27, three rows "prior" to first end of quarter occurrence(2012-03-31) above.

New to pandas, tried several things and stumped for now.

EDIT:

Tried:

```
df.loc[df.index == df.asfreq('Q')][-3]

TypeError: <class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'> type object
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The basic syntax is this:

```
dataframe.loc[dataframe.index < 'date time value'][-n:]
```

Where **n** is the number of subsequent or preceding rows.

For example:

```
In [49]: df.loc[df.index < '2012-03-31 00:00:00'][-3:]
Out[49]: 
                   A
2012-03-28 -0.252526
2012-03-29 -0.708683
2012-03-30 -0.056674
```

You can do more complex things with more operators:

```
In [11]: df.loc[(df.index > '2012-03-31 00:00:00') & (df.index < '2012-06-30 00:00:00')].head()
Out[11]: 
                   A
2012-04-01 -0.172987
2012-04-02 -0.676806
2012-04-03 -1.320243
2012-04-04 -0.222272
2012-04-05  0.700445
```

Note that this really only accounts for this specific case when you're using the [DatetimeIndex](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/generated/pandas.DatetimeIndex.html) class.

Example using df.asfreq('Q'):

```
In [16]: df.loc[(df.index < df.asfreq('Q').index[0])][-3:]
Out[16]: 
                   A
2012-03-28 -1.387065
2012-03-29  1.203649
2012-03-30 -0.668392
```

Comment: Thank you!  Can something like ".asfreq('Q')" be substituted in place of '2012-03-31 00:00:00' above?  (i.e.) df.loc[df.index == df.asfreq('Q')][-3]

Comment: Yes, you can do df.asfreq('Q').index[quarter]. Answer revised above.

Comment: Thank you.  Never ceased to be amazed by capabilities of pandas, and more so, knowledge base people like you so kindly share, thank you!

Comment: @Rayl54292 No problem, I am glad to help. Also, it would be great if you could mark this as solved.